# How can I prevent WPF app from closing main window when opening a new window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use this method to show another window from my main window.

```
   public void DisplayLobbyWindow()
    {
        var d = Application.Current.Dispatcher;

        if (d.CheckAccess())
        {
            new LobbyWindow()
            {
                Owner = this
            }.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            d.BeginInvoke((Action)DisplayLobbyWindow);
        }
    }
```

However, the main application closes when I show the new one. I don't want it to close, I just want to make the first window disappear and show the next one. How's that possible? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I guess it could be because the Owner property is set to the Main Window - however I need it to start up in the main window's location so I set the owner to it. Is there a workaround?

Comment: can't you use this.hide() instead of this.close()?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to hide the window. You can also specify the startup location, since you said you want the new window to pop up where the old window was.

```
public void DisplayLobbyWindow()
{
    ...
        new LobbyWindow()
        {
            Owner = this,
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
        }.Show();

        this.Hide();
    ...
}
```

Then in your second form, subscribe to the `Closed` event:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.LobbyWindow"
    Title="LobbyWindow" Closed="LobbyWindow_OnClosed">
```

So that you can display the first form again. Otherwise, the second window will display and your app will just keep running, invisible.

```
 private void LobbyWindow_OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Owner.Show();
 }
```